# Do we "open bottles" or we "open caps"?

Tags: phrase-usage, image-identification

How should we refer to this action that involves the bottle, [the cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_cap) and the person?

Is she "opening **the bottle**" or "opening **the cap**"?

[image]

Comment: "Open the cap" is fine, as is "open the lid" and "open the door". "Open the bottle" is fine, as is "open the box" and "open the building".

Comment: Complete disambiguation: you "[uncap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncap) the bottle". ;)

Comment: @Ben Open the building? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @insanity re "open the building"... maybe something like this: "The office is locked until 6am, so if you want to start earlier than that you'll need to call security to open the building for you."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

She is **opening the bottle** by **unscrewing the cap** or **removing the cap**.

Edit based on feedback from commeonts: if you say **opening the cap** people will understand what you mean. It might also be a regional idiom in some places.

Comment: This was my thought exactly. _Twisting the cap_ would also work.

Comment: @J.R. Mostly agree, though "unscrewing" has the benefit of indicating that the bottle is being opened, while cases of "twisting" might require further context. I'm just imagining if someone "twisted" a cap and then threw a bottle.

Comment: @Harris - Mostly agree, although [twist-off cap](https://www.lancopromo.com/product/BW200) is pretty standard terminology, I believe.

Comment: Reminds me of [this old commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4_3Jkrp0O8)

Comment: @J.R. - living in NZ I've never heard the term twist-off cap in use. =}

Comment: "Open the cap" is fine, as is "open the lid" and "open the door". "Open the bottle" is fine, as is "open the box" and "open the building".

Comment: Irish. Twist sounds specifically American to me. I'd say "screw the lid off"

Comment: Here in the UK I'm slightly more used to **lid** and **top** rather than **cap** (although all three are common for bottles, "bottle top" is a thing, "bottle cap" sounds alien to me although it does happen). **Unscrewing** is correct; "twist-off" refers to a subset of "crown top" bottle lids (usually on beers); simply ***take off** the lid* (or ***take** the lid **off***) are most common. I'd also suggest simply **undo** as a common term for turning a lid/cap/top to remove it. Similar usage applies to jars (coffee, honey, jam, ...).

Answer (score -5):

I would say technically open the cap is the correct term, however in my experience personally, and most people say "open the bottle". In actuality opening a bottle would probably entail cutting it in half or something, but people don't actually mean that.

Comment: I don't agree that it's correct at all. A cap has no opening and therefore cannot be opened.

Comment: Yeah you're right actually, but opening a cap makes perfect sense in conversational English.

Comment: I don't think "opening a cap" makes any sense in conversational English.

Comment: "opening a cap" makes sense like in "her hands are opening a cap to cosmic enlightenment in conversational English"

Comment: It does raise the interesting question, though, why "open the door" is correct. What's the difference between a cap blocking the entrance to the bottle and a door blocking the entrance to a room? As best I can tell, "door" in that phrase actually refers to the doorway, not the physical door installed in the doorway.

Comment: @chepner I suppose 'open the doorway" is just too unwieldy :) (and "rotate the door" is boring)

Comment: @chepner Doors have an open or closed state. Twist off caps have an on or off state. Valves are open or closed. Lids are on or off. Prepositions in English have no rhyme or reason for the most part.

Comment: @ColleenV Both the door and the cap are physical objects that can block an opening. Are you saying that the difference is that the door remains attached to the doorway when opened, while the cap is completely detached? (I might buy that argument.)

Comment: @chepner No I’m saying that the correct preposition to use is whichever one everyone uses. Prepositions in English are difficult because you can’t reason them out sometimes. You have to memorize a lot of them. For example a squeeze bottle cap is pushed in or pulled out, but it can be open/closed. We can try to make a rule, but there will be lots of exceptions, which I think would be more confusing than just memorizing the correct phrasing.

Comment: Those aren't prepositions here; they are adverbs of state. Just because *some* word choices are all but arbitrary doesn't mean there is *never* some underlying logic.

Comment: @bobbin: "Open the cap" would be fairly normal AmEnglish usage if the cap were somehow attached to the bottle, or part of it.

Comment: If you have a box with a lid, you can "open the lid" no matter whether it's attached to the box (with a hinge) or not.

Comment: @MrLister this might be a regional thing... I should soften the stance I took in my initial comment.

Comment: "Open the cap" is fine, as is "open the lid" and "open the door". "Open the bottle" is fine, as is "open the box" and "open the building".

Comment: @shadowtalker The cap *does* have an opening - but it's a small one, and the bottle only partially fits inside it.  On the other hand, with wine you wouldn't "open the cork", you would "open the bottle", "remove the cork" or "uncork the bottle"

Comment: @eques, except it does. Im Canadian and I say that all the time as well as tons of my friends and coworkers. I agree your right its not proper but alot of people still say it.

Comment: @jamesqf, I hear some people saying that, I definitely hear opening the bottle much more often though. I myself say it all the time and most of my friends from what I remember. Both make sense to me even if they aren't proper. Im canadian dont know if that changes much.

Comment: @shadowtalker, I dont know man im a native english speaker and so many people in Canada say "opening a bottle", it makes perfect sense to me and I say it all the time.